# How to use row level security (RLS) for anonymous users based on an ID value in QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I want to embed a dashboard in a web application that I need to show to multiple anonymous users that would login into the application. I don't want to create QuickSight users for them as that would be expensive because there are too many users for the application. I want these users to be able to see only that data that belongs to their organization. I have been trying to pass the organization Id from a parameter to filter the results but now  I am thinking this is not the right way and RLS is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Cognito offers a free tier of 50,000 monthly active users.
Anonymous user is a option.

https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/pricing/

Comment: Yes I have read about it but couldn't understand how. What I understood was that I should create QuickSight namespaces for each organization and use user ARN to create a RLS mapping permission table. I don't know if this is the correct way. In the end, I need a way to make QuickSight identify the user that is requesting for a dashboard so that I can map the relevant organization to that user for reports.